# Trying to understand what is happening in this Python Function

Tags: python, numpy, k-means, euclidean-distance

```
def closest_centroid(points, centroids):
    """returns an array containing the index to the nearest centroid for each point"""
    distances = np.sqrt(((points - centroids[:, np.newaxis])**2).sum(axis=2))
    return np.argmin(distances, axis=0)
```

Can someone explain the exact working of this function? I currently got `points` which looks like:

```
31998888119     0.94     34
23423423422     0.45     43
....
```

And so on. In this `numpy` array, `points[1]` would be the long ID while `points[2]` is `0.94` and `points[3]` would be `34` for their first entry.

Centroids is just a random selection from this particular array:

```
def initialize_centroids(points, k):
    """returns k centroids from the initial points"""
    centroids = points.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(centroids)
    return centroids[:k]
```

Now I want to get the Euclidean distance from the values of `points` ignoring the first column of IDs and `centroids` (once again ignoring the first column). I don't exactly understand the syntax from the line  `distances = np.sqrt(((points - centroids[:, np.newaxis])**2).sum(axis=2))`. Why exactly are we summing across the third column, while there being a decleration for a new axis: `np.newaxis`? Also along what axis am I supposed to make the `np.argmin` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to think about the dimensions. Let's assume that `k=4` and there are 10 points, so `points.shape = (10,3)`.

Next, `centroids = initialize_centroids(points, 4)` returns an object with dimension `(4,3)`.

Let's break up this line from the inside:

`distances = np.sqrt(((points - centroids[:, np.newaxis])**2).sum(axis=2))`

1. We want to subtract each centroid from each point. Since `points` and `centroids` are 2 dimensional, each `points - centroid` is 2 dimensional. If there were 1 centroid only, then we're ok. But we have 4 centroids! So we need to perform `points - centroids`, for each centroid. Therefore we need another dimension to store this. Hence the addition of a `np.newaxis`.
2. We square it because it's a distance, so we want to convert negatives to positive (and also because we are minimizing Euclidean distance).
3. We're not summing across the third column. In fact we are summing the difference between points and centroid, for each point, for each centroid.
4. `np.argmin()` finds the centroid with the minimum distance. So for each centroid, for each point, find the minimum index (hence `argmin` instead of `min`). That index is the centroid assigned to that point.

Here is an example:

```
points = np.array([
[   1, 2, 4],
[   1, 1, 3],
[   1, 6, 2],
[   6, 2, 3],
[   7, 2, 3],
[   1, 9, 6],
[   6, 9, 1],
[   3, 8, 6],
[   10, 9, 6],
[   0, 2, 0],
])

centroids = initialize_centroids(points, 4)

print(centroids)
array([[10,  9,  6],
   [ 3,  8,  6],
   [ 6,  2,  3],
   [ 1,  1,  3]])

distances = (pts - centroids[:, np.newaxis])**2

print(distances)
array([[[ 81,  49,   4],
    [ 81,  64,   9],
    [ 81,   9,  16],
    [ 16,  49,   9],
    [  9,  49,   9],
    [ 81,   0,   0],
    [ 16,   0,  25],
    [ 49,   1,   0],
    [  0,   0,   0],
    [100,  49,  36]],

   [[  4,  36,   4],
    [  4,  49,   9],
    [  4,   4,  16],
    [  9,  36,   9],
    [ 16,  36,   9],
    [  4,   1,   0],
    [  9,   1,  25],
    [  0,   0,   0],
    [ 49,   1,   0],
    [  9,  36,  36]],

   [[ 25,   0,   1],
    [ 25,   1,   0],
    [ 25,  16,   1],
    [  0,   0,   0],
    [  1,   0,   0],
    [ 25,  49,   9],
    [  0,  49,   4],
    [  9,  36,   9],
    [ 16,  49,   9],
    [ 36,   0,   9]],

   [[  0,   1,   1],
    [  0,   0,   0],
    [  0,  25,   1],
    [ 25,   1,   0],
    [ 36,   1,   0],
    [  0,  64,   9],
    [ 25,  64,   4],
    [  4,  49,   9],
    [ 81,  64,   9],
    [  1,   1,   9]]])

print(distances.sum(axis=2))
array([[134, 154, 106,  74,  67,  81,  41,  50,   0, 185],
   [ 44,  62,  24,  54,  61,   5,  35,   0,  50,  81],
   [ 26,  26,  42,   0,   1,  83,  53,  54,  74,  45],
   [  2,   0,  26,  26,  37,  73,  93,  62, 154,  11]])

# The minimum of the first 4 centroids is index 3. The minimum of the second 4 centroids is index 3 again.

print(np.argmin(distances.sum(axis=2), axis=0))
array([3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3])
```